# Views SQL query not showing in production

Tags: views, 9

I don't see any of my data from my view on my production website. I'd like to compare the data generated in the view compared to my local (which is working fine).

But in my production website, I don't see the executed query
[image]
Even if all the config seems to be set the right way (at least, the same as my working local)

[image]

Do I have something else to configure ? Maybe inside a settings.php ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it ! I had this written in a production config file

```
$config['views.settings']['ui']['show']['sql_query']['enabled'] = FALSE;
$config['views.settings']['ui']['show']['performance_statistics'] = FALSE;
```